# Place ticks in the middle of each color in descrete colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I need to change the placement of my colorbar ticks and I need help in doing so. I have tried a few things so far but not one of them worked in a satisfactory way.

I have a dataframe of the following type:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
country_iso = ['RU', 'FR', 'HU', 'AT', 'US', 'ES', 'DE', 'CH', 'LV', 'LU']
my_randoms=[random.uniform(0.0, 0.3) for _ in range (len(country_iso))]
df = pd.DataFrame({'iso':country_iso, 'values':my_randoms})
df.loc[df.iso.str.contains('US')]= ['US', 0]
df['binned']=pd.cut(df['values'], bins=[-0.01, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3], labels=[0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3])
df.binned = pd.to_numeric(df.binned, errors='coerce')
df = df[['iso', 'binned']]
```

As you can see, this is a dataframe with iso-country values as one column and some as a second column a binned value between 0 and 0.3. The US has the value 0 and I want it to have a distinct colour. I then proceed to create a basemap with a shapefile from [natural earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, colors as clr, cm
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter    
import numpy as np

shapefile_path = #path to your shapefile

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,20))
m = Basemap(resolution='c', # c, l, i, h, f or None
            projection='mill',
            llcrnrlat=-62, urcrnrlat=85,
            llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180)
m.readshapefile(shapefile_path+r'\ne_110m_admin_0_countries', 'areas')
df_poly = pd.DataFrame({
    'shapes': [Polygon(np.array(shape), True) for shape in m.areas],
    'iso': [gs['ISO_A2'] for gs in m.areas_info]
})
df_poly = df_poly.merge(df, on='iso', how='inner', indicator=True)

cmap = clr.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom blue', ['#d0dfef', '#24466b'], N=7)
cmap._init()
cmap._lut[0,: ] = np.array([200,5,5,200])/255
pc = PatchCollection(df_poly[df_poly[df.columns[1]].notnull()].shapes, zorder=2)
norm = clr.Normalize()
pc.set_facecolor(cmap(norm(df_poly[df_poly[df.columns[1]].notnull()][df.columns[1]].values)))
ax.add_collection(pc)

mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
mapper.set_array(df_poly[df_poly[df.columns[1]].notnull()][df.columns[1]])
clb = plt.colorbar(mapper, shrink=0.19)
```

I create a cmap of blues but change the first colour to red. This is because I want countries with the value 0 to have a distinct colour. Everything works splendidly, but if you have a look at the colorbar, the ticks are off-center.

[image]

Any chance someone knows how to correct my code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're doing `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(..., N=7)` but 7 doesn't "nicely" go into 0.3. Try `N=6`?

Comment: I'm unsure about the role of "zero" here. If you place 0 in the middle of the red part of the colormap, it means e.g. that values between -0.025 and +0.025 are colorized in red, not only 0 itself. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: You could easily ask your question using minimal example. Please do so, you'll have much more chances to get a good answer, and it will be much more useful for others.

Comment: I have reduced the code a lot and did some further reduction after reading your comment @Tom. I am somewhat new to python and even more so to plotting and was unsure how to reduce it further. It seems that one doesn't need basemap to answer the question, but I didn't know that. As for the colour segments, unfortunately n=6 doesn't solve the issue,though it does look better. As for the 0 values, the interval around zero is so small that it only captures countries with the value 0.

Comment: I think your question is ok as it is. Everybody can see that you're new to SO. In the future, wherever possible, try to post example code that can be run 'out of the box' for problems of the 'this code does not work correctly'-type. See [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more info on this. Note also that you have some indentation problem in your code -- I'm guessing that is from reducing your original code to the displayed version.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the indentation. Yeah, you can't run it as it is. But if you download the shapefile from the link I provided and change the shapefilepath, it should run. It's still messy though with the range of imported modules and the code in general.

Comment: I found one way to make it work: add `bounds=np.arange(-0.05,0.35,0.05)` and change the colorbar to `clb = plt.colorbar(mapper, shrink=0.19, ticks=bounds, boundaries=bounds+0.025)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cooking down your example to the essentials, you can achieve what you want by extending the range that you pass to your mapper. I guess that it is up to the specific use case whether it makes sense to extend the colormap to negative values. Anyway, here is a full example without `Basemap` and `shapefiles`, which are not needed for this problem.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, colors as clr, cm
import numpy as np

fig= plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot2grid((1,20),(0,0), colspan=19)
cax = plt.subplot2grid((1,20),(0,19))

upper = 0.3
lower = 0.0
N = 7

cmap = clr.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    'custom blue', ['#d0dfef', '#24466b'], N=N
)
cmap._init()
cmap._lut[0,: ] = np.array([200,5,5,200])/255.0
norm = clr.Normalize()

mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)

deltac = (upper-lower)/(2*(N-1))

mapper.set_array(np.linspace(lower-deltac,upper+deltac,10)) #<-- the 10 here is pretty arbitrary
clb = fig.colorbar(mapper, shrink=0.19, cax=cax)

plt.show()
```

I had some problems with the vertical extend of the colorbar, which is why I chose to use the `cax` keyword. Note also that in Python 2 there is a small problem with integer divisions. I therefore changed the division from `/255` to `/255.0`. The final result looks like this:

[image: result of above code]

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**:

Apparently the call to `norm()` alters the state of the `Normalize` object. By providing a new `Normalize` object to the `ScalarMappable` constructor, the code starts working as intended. I'm still baffled why this happens. Anyway, below the full code to produce the plot and the colorbar (note that I changed the figure size and the colorbar scaling):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, colors as clr, cm
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import pandas as pd
import random
country_iso = ['RU', 'FR', 'HU', 'AT', 'US', 'ES', 'DE', 'CH', 'LV', 'LU']
my_randoms=[random.uniform(0.0, 0.3) for _ in range (len(country_iso))]
df = pd.DataFrame({'iso':country_iso, 'values':my_randoms})
df.loc[df.iso.str.contains('US')]= ['US', 0]
df['binned']=pd.cut(df['values'], bins=[-0.01, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3], labels=[0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3])
df.binned = pd.to_numeric(df.binned, errors='coerce')
df = df[['iso', 'binned']]

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

shapefile_path = 'shapefiles/'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()#figsize=(10,20))

upper = 0.3
lower = 0.0
N = 7

deltac = (upper-lower)/(2*(N-1))

m = Basemap(resolution='c', # c, l, i, h, f or None
            projection='mill',
            llcrnrlat=-62, urcrnrlat=85,
            llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180,
            ax = ax,
            )
m.readshapefile(shapefile_path+r'ne_110m_admin_0_countries', 'areas')
df_poly = pd.DataFrame({
    'shapes': [Polygon(np.array(shape), True) for shape in m.areas],
    'iso': [gs['ISO_A2'] for gs in m.areas_info]
})

df_poly = df_poly.merge(df, on='iso', how='inner', indicator=True)

cmap = clr.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom blue', ['#d0dfef', '#24466b'], N=N)
cmap._init()
cmap._lut[0,: ] = np.array([200,5,5,200])/255.0

pc = PatchCollection(df_poly[df_poly[df.columns[1]].notnull()].shapes, zorder=2)
norm = clr.Normalize()

pc.set_facecolor(cmap(norm(df_poly[df_poly[df.columns[1]].notnull()][df.columns[1]].values)))
ax.add_collection(pc)

mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=clr.Normalize(), cmap=cmap)
mapper.set_array([lower-deltac,upper+deltac])
clb = plt.colorbar(mapper, shrink=0.55)

plt.show()
```

The resulting plot looks like this:

[image: result of the second patch of code]

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for taking the time to reduce the code to the essentials and to find an answer. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to adjust your answer to make it work in my case so far, but I'm sure I'll get there.

Comment: @Wald basically all you need to change is the `mapper.set_array` line in your code. You can entirely de-couple the data that you plot from the data you use to adjust your colorbar. This is why I chose a simple `numpy` array to do the adjustment.

Comment: @Wald actually you can skip even the `numpy.linspace` and just write `mapper.set_array([lower-deltac,upper+deltac])`.

Comment: I feel really stupid, but what do I need to change exactly? Changing the mapper.set_array was the first thing I did after reading your answer, but for some reason this doesn't fix it. I suppose it could be that I might have to adjust upper/lower and deltac from your example (I just copied them), but these are the values that I use. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: @Wald I think I would have to see your altered code (maybe posted below your original question; at least all the lines that you changed). However, I see you found a solution already, so maybe it's not worth the effort.

Comment: I do get the correct colobar when running your code (although I have to delete the shrink argument which throws me an error). But somehow in my code it doesnt change a thing. The altered code is all of my code above and `upper, lower, N = 0.3, 0.0, 7
deltac = (upper-lower)/(2*(N-1))
mapper.set_array(np.linspace(lower-deltac,upper+deltac,10))` instead of the previous mapper.set_array. I want to understand why it doesn't work, but I totally understand if you don't want to spend any more time on the problem.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I really appreciate the time and effort you spend to help me. That works perfectly.